# To change column in crystal report in details sections

Tags: crystal-reports

```
<Column Title1>                                    <Column Title 1>
  Row1                                                  Row6
  Row2                                                  Row7
  Row3                                                  Row8
  Row4                                                  Row9
  Row5                                                  Row10
```

I want to show my data as aove format in details section of Crystal Report. Please ehlp me what i can do?

Comment: You should look for creating Mailing Label Report

Comment: NO sir i just want to Create simple report with multiple column

Answer (score 0):

select the details section , right click and select "Section expert" . Check the check box "Format with multiple columns" and on the layout tab at the top specify the number of columns

Comment: Thank you very much @Lan but I didnt get number of columns in layout tab in (Crystal Report XI). Please help me..

Comment: It is available just for the details section. What is your Crystal version ?